# Is it possible to connect with access database saved in the Box folder?

Tags: python, box

we need to save access database in the Box folder. In order to access the database, company login ID and password is required. I am working with a project based on python and Excel and exploring the possibilities to connect with access database saved in the box folder. Looking for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Box Drive](https://www.box.com/en-gb/drive) from Windows or MacOS, with MS Access installed on that machine, you can connect to the Access database by using its local Box Drive file path. Box Drive mounts the Box file system and presents it in either Windows Explorer or Finder.